# What font is used on Junghans' Max Bill watch face?

Tags: font-identification

First the caveats: yes I did go over all the font-id resources i could think of, including all the ones listed on the FAQ on this site. I've already spent a couple days on this and would already have started a clone font myself if I didn't know for sure the font is commercial and i will need to license it regardless, because well it is used in a product after all.

The font in question is used in the watch face bellow:
[image: max bill watch]

Every single font-id software/site gives me either a closed 4 or a square font.

here is the cleaned up digits i used to id via OCR offerings:
[image: max bill digits]

The "Sequel Rounded Extended" does have a few round digits that are very similar, but 7 and 4 are way off. Millar family is closer on the 7 and 4, but still very far away.

I'd appreciate any pointers on finding the right one to license. Thanks.

Comment: I have a feeling that it's a custom typeface, not a commercially available font, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Not everything is a font

I believe that you are correct that the font is **Sequel Rounded Extended**.

To me, it matches perfectly.

[image]

The only outlier seems to be the 4 which they most likely made a custom glyph for because the closed variant didn't fit the aesthetic.

Additionally, the C seems to have been edited to be more open but the source image isn't very high quality so I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 8):

This is a custom typeface designed by Max Bill for his original kitchen clock, *Exacta* in 1957. A beautiful specimen of Swiss Bauhaus design. According to this source:

> Bill designed a special typeface, numbers and logo for the product,
>   which was made by Junghans, Germany.
>
> [Source: Design is fine. History is mine.](http://www.design-is-fine.org/post/83742929532/max-bill-kitchen-clock-exacta-1957-bill)

[image: Max Bill **Kitchen Clock** 1956-57]
*Max Bill **Kitchen Clock** 1956-57* (image courtesy of [MoMA.org](https://www.moma.org/collection/works/139247))

I might also add that Ovaryraptor's answer is indeed correct. The **Sequel Rounded** family wasn't released until 2017, so the font itself technically did not exist when Max Bill created the original piece. But this font *was inspired* by Max Bill and designed to look like the typeface he created for the clock faces:

> Sequel Rounded is a post-Max Bill font by OGJ type design, berlin, and
>   is developed in close cooperation with the Max Bill Georges
>   Vantongerloo foundation in switzerland.
>
> [Source: Sequel Rounded on MyFonts](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/ogj-typedesign/sequel-rounded/)